# Bootstrap Nav Tabs doesn't work with dynamic content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I try to get my dynamic content in tabs but it doesn't work the way it supposed to:

`here is my codes`

```
                                <div class="col-md-3">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
@foreach($faqs as $count => $faq)
<li role="presentation" @if($count == 0) class="active" @endif>
    <a href="#{{$faq->id}}" aria-controls="#{{ $faq->id }}" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">{{ $faq->title }}</a>
</li>
@endforeach
</ul>
                                </div><!--end col-3-->

                                <div class="col-md-9">
<div class="tab-content">
@foreach($faqs as $count => $faq)
<div @if($count == 0) class="tab-pane active" @else class="tab-pane" @endif id="{{$faq->id}}">
@foreach($faq->subfaqs as $subs)
<div class="panel-group" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true" id="#{{$subs->id}}">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
            <h4 class="panel-title">
                <a href="#{{$subs->id}}" data-toggle="collapse"><i class="fa-icon fa fa-arrow-circle-o-up"></i>{{$subs->title}}</a>
            </h4>
        </div>

        <div id="{{$subs->id}}" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel">
            <div class="panel-body">
                {!!$subs->body!!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@endforeach
</div>
@endforeach
</div>
                                </div><!--end col-9-->
```

and my `script`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $('.collapse').collapse("show");
</script>
```

#### Issues

1. My Tabs `<li>` won't load (it always load my first tab)
2. My Drop-down's `collapse` not working (can't open/close them)

Comment: @user770 this is what this code does https://ibb.co/k8eDuS

Comment: @user770 `@foreach($faq->subfaqs as $subs)` the id's of `$subs`

Comment: when i hit `panel-title` , `panel-body` show be shown

Comment: @user770 would you mind help with it? `ps` also tabs in `left side` wont show e.g. when i click shipping still i see details of payment tab

Comment: See: https://www.google.com/search?q=how%20to%20make%20a%20collapsing%20navbar%20menu

Comment: @user770 bro if i could find my solution by googling i wouldn't ask here! thanks anyway.